# Module not found in miniconda installed automatically with RStudio when loading pm4py

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, miniconda

I've installed miniconda with RStudio on Ubuntu in order to use the package pm4py.

When I try to load the package I receive the error ModuleNotFound.
I suppose it's because it tries to look for the package in the built-in ubuntu installation of python.

How can I set the right path to the installed miniconda and its modules?

```
> library(pm4py)
No non-system installation of Python could be found.
Would you like to download and install Miniconda?
Miniconda is an open source environment management system for Python.
See https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html for more details.

Would you like to install Miniconda? [Y/n]: Y

...[output stuff here]...

* Miniconda has been successfully installed at '/home/dario/.local/share/r-miniconda'.

> library(pm4py)
> discovery_alpha(data)
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pm4py'
```

Comment: Please add commands and original outputs, this is not reproducible.

Comment: Can you load pm4py using a python console ? Like launching python in terminal and calling `import pm4py` ?

Comment: Does not seem to workPython 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pm4py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pm4py

Answer (score 1):

After installing pm4py in r, one needs also to launch `pm4py::install_pm4py()` . This will download ad install pm4py in miniconda.